# c# - Como fechar uma instancia específica do internet explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

Consigo com este código.

```
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")) {p.Kill();}
```

Porém preciso fechar apenas uma instancia pegando talvez pelo titulo da janela.

Esta é a janela que precisa ser fechada. Obs: não tenho o handle dela e sim, é uma janela e não um alert javascript ou algo assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT:**

com a sugestão do @Bruno Warmling
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RESULTADO VARIAVEL P:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RESULTADO windowtextlist

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a referencia para `Microsoft Internet Controls` na aba COM.

Adicione nos usings a referencia para a biblioteca importada anteriormente.

```
using SHDocVw
```

Depois faça da seguinte forma:

```
const string janelaParaFechar = "Google";
foreach (InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindows())
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).Equals("iexplore", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && ie.Document.nameProp == janelaParaFechar)
    {
        ie.Quit();
    }
}
```

Se essa não funcionar, há outro jeito..
Inclua as funções abaixo:

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

private extern static bool EnumThreadWindows(int threadId, EnumWindowsProc callback, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

private extern static int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxCount);

private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

public static IList<string> GetWindowText(Process p)
{
    List<string> titles = new List<string>();
    foreach (ProcessThread t in p.Threads)
    {
        EnumThreadWindows(t.Id, (hWnd, lParam) =>
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(200);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, text, 200);
            titles.Add(text.ToString());
            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    return titles;
}
```

Depois utilize da seguinte forma:

```
string janelaParaFechar = "Google - Internet Explorer";
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"))
{
    var windowTextList = GetWindowText(process);
    if (windowTextList?.Count > 0 && windowTextList.Contains(janelaParaFechar))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas então você está usando Edge e não o internet explorer?

Comment: uso o webbrowser do c# e ele usa IE

Comment: Incluí mais uma forma de fazer

Comment: windowTextList vem com 73 itens mas nenhum é a aba que tem que ser fechada

Comment: e só retorna um processo pra você?

Comment: sim só há essa janela do IE aberta, o processo está retornando certo

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e colocar os resultados que vieram

Comment: @MiltonMachadoPereira mas pq você esta tentando fazer isso matando o processo, se você tem um `WebBrowser`? Essa aplicação com o `WebBrowser` é sua? você tem controle sobre a programação dela??

Comment: pq essa janela de erro é aberta em uma nova janela, então eu perco o controle sobre ela, só daria certo de outro jeito se eu conseguisse abrir a janela de erro num novo webbrowser.

Comment: editei a questao

Comment: Cara, o processo tem que ser `iexplore` e não `explorer`. Explorer é o gerenciador de janelas do Windows e não o Windows Explorer. Tenta mudar lá

Comment: dai nao vem nenhum processo

Comment: Mas então você deve informar o nome do processo host dessa janela... e **não** o `explorer`.

Comment: pior que eu acho que essa janela nao tem processo ou é um processo filho, que nao aparece no gerenciador de tarefas

Comment: consegui com o findWindowByCaption do windows... pegando pelo texto "Ocorreu o seguinte erro: -- Caixa de diálogo Página da Web" que fica no title da janela